# Executing JavaScript in a webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have an application that executes JavaScript in a webview with this code and it works fine:

```
ivWeb.loadUrl(url);
```

I will be receiving some JavaScript code as a text string. Is there some way to execute that?

Answer (score 2):

call:

```
ivWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I am doing these, but it still doesn't works. I can load the code in a HTML from URL and it works, but if i receive and put the code in a html, the code doesn't play.